# Google Repo with Gitlab subgroup

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to use Google Repo. I followed [Harrow's blogpost](https://harrow.io/blog/using-repo-to-manage-complex-software-projects/) to set it up. They use

`<remote  name="origin" fetch=".." />`

My Repo manifest is in `git@gitlab.com:company/mysubgroup/manifest.git`

The repositories I want to manage with Repo live in a Gitlab subgroup, with URLs of the form `git@gitlab.com:company/mysubgroup/myrepo.git`.

`repo sync` can't find the repositories:

```
Fetching project hardware_launch.git
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Do I need to change the `fetch` attribute?
How can I check which URL repo tries to clone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the subgroup but access via ssh instead of https.
Changing the remote's `fetch` to `ssh://git@gitlab.com/company` works. (note the `/` instead of `:`)